# Pysnmp Command Responder with GetNext or Walk operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, snmp, pysnmp

I am implementing a Pysnmp responder that receives SNMP GET/SET requests currently and would like to extend with Walk, getNext and getBulk operations. All the OID and its values are stored in key-value in a file.

What I have tried is to use readNextVars() method from instrum.AbstractMibInstrumController class where I iterate over OID's list by calling self.readVars() within readNextVars()

Below is a code snippet showing only GET request and SET request is similar but it writes value to its respective OID in oid.json file.

```
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdrsp, context
from pysnmp.carrier.asynsock.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.smi import instrum, error
from pysnmp.proto.api import v2c
import json

class SnmpData:

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()

        config.addSocketTransport(
            self.snmpEngine,
            udp.domainName,
            udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode((host, port))
        )
        config.addV1System(self.snmpEngine, 'my-area', 'public', contextName='my-context')

        config.addVacmUser(self.snmpEngine, 2, 'my-area', 'noAuthNoPriv', (1, 3, 6), (4, 5, 7))

        self.snmpContext = context.SnmpContext(self.snmpEngine)

    def snmp_run_command(self):
        self.snmpContext.registerContextName(
            v2c.OctetString('my-context'),
            FileInstrumController()
        )

        cmdrsp.GetCommandResponder(self.snmpEngine, self.snmpContext)
        cmdrsp.SetCommandResponder(self.snmpEngine, self.snmpContext)
        cmdrsp.NextCommandResponder(self.snmpEngine, self.snmpContext)
        cmdrsp.BulkCommandResponder(self.snmpEngine, self.snmpContext)

        self.snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)

        try:
            self.snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
        except:
            self.snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
            return "yes"

    def main(self):
        self.snmp_run_command()

class FileInstrumController(instrum.AbstractMibInstrumController):
    def readVars(self, vars, acInfo=(None, None)):
        try:
            data = None
            final_data = None
            with open('oid.json') as f:
                data = json.load(f)

                if str(vars[0][0]) in data.keys())):
                    final_data = data[str(vars[0][0])]
                    return [(vars[0][0], v2c.OctetString(str(final_data)))]
                else:
                    return [(vars[0][0], v2c.OctetString(str("Not a Valid OID")))]
        except IOError:
            raise error.SmiError

    def readNextVars(self, vars, acInfo=(None, None))
        # get oid & split and match if in file than return its value
        # else return invalid oid and break but its not breaking 
        # and sending continuously requests of next oid (OID + 1)
```

Here is the oid file (oid.json)

```
{
      "1.3.6.1.1.999.1.1.0": 1,
      "1.3.6.1.1.999.1.2.0": 2,
      "1.3.6.1.1.999.1.3.0": 3,
      "1.3.6.1.1.999.1.4.0": 4,
      "1.3.6.1.1.999.1.5.0": 5,
      "1.3.6.1.1.999.1.6.0": 100,
      "1.3.6.1.1.999.1.7.0": 200,
      "1.3.6.1.1.999.1.8.0": 300,
      "1.3.6.1.1.999.1.9.0": 400,
      "1.3.6.1.1.999.1.10.0": 500
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you wanted to achieve. Maybe you should take a look at `snmpsim` instead, and convert your own `oid.json` to a `.simprec` file.